# Directive not working when html is called from pipes

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-directive

I have a page containing some HTML content which is generated from my custom pipe like below.

```
this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<div ><img imageholder  class="loading-null-img" src="' + file_url + '" /></div>');
```

And I have a custom directive named `ImageholderDirective`

```
 @Directive({
  selector: '[imageholder]' // Attribute selector
})
export class ImageholderDirective {

  constructor() {
    alert('Hello ImageholderDirective Directive');
  }

}
```

but the directive is not working, when we try to load the HTML form pipe.why?

Comment: The use of rendering HTML is severely restricted now in Angular. You can only render basic HTML. You'll need to restructure your approach. Perhaps render the HTML first with the image under it?

Comment: HTML rendering si working poperly,but the problem is ,imageholder directive is not triggered

Comment: Yep understood. But your directive will never be triggered if done by an HTML render in that way. They've locked it down so much you won't be able to do it.